# Override response in Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

And view:

```
class UserListView(ListAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

And as expected on a GET request i get a response like

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "First",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Second",
    }
]
```

What should i use to get response like this:

```
{
   'users': [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "First",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Second",
        }
    ]
}
```

I think it's easy, but can't understand how.

Comment: The `[` and the `'users':` don't fit together. You should provide valid JSON as your desired result.

Comment: The response you want is not valid json,  instead try { 'users': []}